# How to read gzipped binary MNIST database R without download to local file?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read MNIST database from URL using following code:

```
f <- gzcon(url("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"))
readBin(f, integer(), n=4, endian="big") # read header: 2051 10000  28  28
data <- matrix(readBin(f, integer(), size=1, n=28*28*10000, endian="big"), 10000, 28*28, byrow=TRUE)
```

Obtained data matrix contains "shifted" images, because the first call to readbin() does not move a file pointer, so the second call to readBin() rereads the same header.

Related topics are [How to read MNIST database in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521571/how-to-read-mnist-database-in-r) and [Read gzipped csv directly from a url in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548630/read-gzipped-csv-directly-from-a-url-in-r) , but it does not help to solve a problem.

Thank You for help!